# Enforcing that all columns have different values

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger, check-constraints

A particular `val#` should be in no more than one column. Multiple columns can be `empty` though. (I don't want to use `NULL` instead of `empty`.)

```
CREATE TYPE vals AS ENUM ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', ... 'empty');
CREATE TABLE some_table
( ...
  column1 vals NOT NULL,
  column2 vals NOT NULL,
  column3 vals NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT some_table_column_vals_check CHECK (???)
... );
```

Valid combinations e.g.:

```
column1: val1
column2: val2
column3: val4

column1: val1
column2: empty
column3: empty
```

Invalid combinations e.g.:

```
column1: val1
column2: val3
column3: val3

column1: val2
column2: empty
column3: val2
```

Is there a neat way to do this with a (preferably not too long) constraint, or should I write a trigger function for that?

Comment: I'd consider redesigning the table. Have an ID column and one value per row. A UNIQUE constraint (or composite primary key) will prevent duplicates. BTW, nulls aren't dangerous, they serve a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a rather painful `case` expression in a `check` constraint:

```
alter table some_table add constraint chk_some_tablefields
    check ( (val1 not in (val2, val3) or val1 = 'empty') and
            (val2 not in (val3) or val2 = 'empty')
          );
```

However, I would caution you about your data structure.  You should probably have a junction/association table with one row per val and `some_table` id.  Or you might want to just store the values in an array, if you want a variable number of them.

Comment: Thank's you're right. I also thought of some JSON array datatype, but finally decided to have them in another table and use UNIQUE constraints. It works great.